# How do I put a set of random letters into an aligned string in python 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, random

I'm trying to create a random set of letters and put it inside a string, and I'm using **python 3.6** here (I have tested some other ways to do this, but they are outdated and only work in the earliest versions of python 3 and below).

I am using this:

```
import random
import string

randomletters = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 4)
for randomletters in randomletters: # gather the elements into a string
    stringofrndletters = "".join(randomletters)
    print(stringofrndletters)
```

The output looks like:

```
>> print(stringofrndletters)
r
B
X
g
```

But I want the output to be similar to this:

```
>> print(stringofrndletters)
rBXg
```

Comment: Just remove the `for` line.

Comment: Moving my comment here as the other (incorrect) answer has been deleted: Your `for` loop doesn't make any sense, and `"".join()` already concatenates list elements into a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for a for loop.

```
randomletters = random.sample(string.ascii_letters, 4)
print(''.join(randomletters))
```